# How Can I install Azure Service Fabric SDK Version 2.5.216(VS2015)

Tags: sdk, azure-service-fabric

My Project template is based on Service fabric SDK 2.5.216 but Web installer is not listing out this version since it is older version.Can somebody provide me SDK or tell me anyway to download it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, install in this order.

- Runtime: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/E/2EE80964-74C2-4464-A7A1-4A587E8DE255/MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.5.216.0.msi
- SDK: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/E/2EE80964-74C2-4464-A7A1-4A587E8DE255/MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.5.216.msi
- Tools: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/E/2EE80964-74C2-4464-A7A1-4A587E8DE255/MicrosoftAzureServiceFabricTools.VS140.en-us.msi