# Powershell script to install Azure Service Fabric SDK, runtime and tools silently

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to write a script to download an install Azure Service Fabric SDK, runtime and tools into a few servers.

My issue is that the installer provided [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) is a Web Installer, and does not support silent mode.

I found a guy that solved this issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/710). His code:

```
# Install Service Fabric Runtime
Invoke-WebRequest "http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/2/1/3217654F-6882-4CEA-BD51-49287EDECE9B/MicrosoftServiceFabric.6.0.232.9494.exe" -OutFile "C:\ServiceFabricRuntime.exe" -UseBasicParsing; \
Start-Process "C:\ServiceFabricRuntime.exe" -ArgumentList '/AcceptEULA', '/QUIET' -NoNewWindow -Wait; \
rm "C:\ServiceFabricRuntime.exe"

# Install Service Fabric SDK
Invoke-WebRequest "http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/2/1/3217654F-6882-4CEA-BD51-49287EDECE9B/MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.8.232.msi" -OutFile "C:\ServiceFabricSDK.msi" -UseBasicParsing; \
Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList '/i', 'C:\ServiceFabricSDK.msi', '/passive', '/quiet', '/norestart', '/qn' -NoNewWindow -Wait; \
rm "C:\ServiceFabricSDK.msi"
```

As you can see, he's using direct links to the .msi installers (as well as other guys are doing in other threads like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212235/where-can-i-find-previous-versions-of-azure-service-fabric-sdks) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183600/how-can-i-install-azure-service-fabric-sdk-version-2-5-216vs2015) answers.).

So my questions is, how do i get a direct link to the msi with the latest version of these installers?

And the follow up question would be, is there a universal link that will automatically download the latest version of these tools?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is not exactly what you asked for but you can use `Web Platform Installer Command Line` to install `WebPI` products silently. The idea is to download `WebPICMD` and run installation of `Service Fabric SDK` from the cmd line. The powershell script can look like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/F/F/CFF3A0B8-99D4-41A2-AE1A-496C08BEB904/WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi" -OutFile "C:\WebPlatformInstaller.msi" -UseBasicParsing;
Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList '/i', 'C:\WebPlatformInstaller.msi', '/passive', '/quiet', '/norestart', '/qn' -NoNewWindow -Wait; 
rm "C:\WebPlatformInstaller.msi"

WebPICMD.exe /Install /Products:MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK /AcceptEULA
```

Product `MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK` will install latest version of `Service Fabric SDK` and `Service Fabric Runtime` silently.

If you want to install something different from the `WebPI` run :

`WebPICMD.exe /List /ListOption:All`

This command will list all of the available products, just grab the id of the product and run install command.

More about `WebPICMD` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-v4-command-line-webpicmdexe-rtw-release).

Answer (score 1):

To add on the answer above, if WebPlatformCMD gives you Windows' UAC consent window issues, you can use [PSEXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) tools to run the installer as system account, avoiding that problem.

Example code:

```
 Invoke-WebRequest "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287166" -OutFile "$env:temp\WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi" -UseBasicParsing

 Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList "/i $env:temp\WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi /passive /quiet /norestart /qn" -NoNewWindow -Wait

 $psToolsPath = "$env:temp\pstools"
 New-Item $psToolsPath -ItemType directory -force -erroraction silentlycontinue
 Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip -OutFile $psToolsPath\PSTools.zip

 Expand-Archive "$psToolsPath\PSTools.zip" $psToolsPath -force
 cd $psToolsPath
 Start-Process psexec64 -ArgumentList "-s /accepteula WebPICMD.exe /Install /Products:MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK /AcceptEULA"
```

Small note on SteppingRazor's answer above.

You can ease out the ArgumentList Parameter value like this:

```
Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList "/i C:\WebPlatformInstaller.msi /passive /quiet /norestart /qn -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Instead of

```
Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList '/i', 'C:\WebPlatformInstaller.msi', '/passive', '/quiet', '/norestart', '/qn' -NoNewWindow -Wait;
```

Then using variables in the string is also easier.